# Full screen mode in a dual monitor work

Tags: multiple-monitors, screen, monitor

I used to work with two displays. As usual I make full screen on the second monitor for watching web video while continuing to work on the laptop monitor.

In Ubuntu it's always opening in full screen mode on the laptop monitor.

Is it possible to open full screen on the second monitor if so,how can I do this?

Comment: @Tim Web video = YouTube video is most cases? Also solution #3 (https://github.com/ali1234/fullscreenhack) proposed in the other question actually works cross-browser whenever Flash is used for video playback (which is still mostly the case). Also the behaviour he describes doesn't happen when watching videos using HTML5 playback in fullscreen (at least in Firefox).

Comment: @alex so it is a problem with flash.

Comment: @Tim Most likely... If its not that it must be something exotic... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on this problem for a LONG time.

Its a compatibility issue with the browser + plugins.

Here's what I did

A workaround that accidentally turned out to be quite handy.
It may or maynot be the "right way" but the only way i could find... anywhere.

1. Set second display (tv, monitor, whatnot) as "Seperate Xserver"

   - this may temporarily screw up Hardware Composition.

   Check xorg.conf for any errors.
2. You Might not be able to run 3d Shells (gnome3, unity3d, etwill be able to run unity fallback, gnome flashback metacity, etc on the primary monitor. The aux monitor may be a naked Xserver which you can not drag windows onto.
3. Terminal commands... I think, someone correct me if im wrong.

```
DISPLAY=:0.1 xterm &
```

gets you a basic xterm on the second screen.
 
Or you can...

```
DISPLAY=:0.1 startlxde &
```

For me, ran light desktop on the second screen without issues.

Its handy because the second display can run another user, completely seperated from the main desktop. I use it for chrooting and virtual machines.

Comment: Did you ever try https://github.com/ali1234/fullscreenhack ? That sounds insane...

Comment: Didnt work for me.

Comment: Too bad :-( Though I finally found a good solution to recommend for that long-standing problem... Ever tried Xephyr, its not very elegant but using that I never had any of your symptoms.

Comment: Yeah nesting works. But it's not as fun as dual shells.